# Adding Subtitles to a VAAPI/QSV 10bit Accelerated Transcode

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I've been converting some of my BluRays to watch on a streaming machine elsewhere in the house but I'm having trouble when it comes to burning subtitles, or more specifically, I'm having trouble figuring out what FFMPEG wants from me to make the process actually work.

It's easy enough to do this in software, but I'm using hardware decoding and encoding and that's where the complexity seems to come from (VAAPI/QSV for decoding, QSV AV1 for encoding).

I can use the following when dealing with SDR content:

```
-vf "scale_vaapi=w='min(1920,iw)':h=-8:mode=nl_anamorphic:format=p010le:extra_hw_frames=120,hwmap=derive_device=qsv,format=qsv"
```

And the following when dealing with HDR content:

```
-vf "scale_vaapi=w='min(1920,iw)':h=-8:mode=nl_anamorphic:format=p010le,tonemap_vaapi=format=p010le:t=bt709:m=bt709:p=bt709:extra_hw_frames=120,hwmap=derive_device=qsv,format=qsv"
```

But I cannot, in the hundreds of permutations I've tried now, find a single way to shoehorn subtitle baking into the process. I'm using SRT files for simplicity, so I just need to add `subtitles=blah.srt` somewhere to get it to work, but the crux of the issue is knowing where in the chain it needs to go and more importantly, what supporting arguments it needs with it (e.g. hwupload, hwdownload, and their associated switches, etc).

Pretty much every single attempt just results in:

> Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'graph 0 input from stream 0:0' and the filter 'auto_scale_0'
> Error reinitializing filters!
> Failed to inject frame into filter network: Function not implemented

So, what am I missing?